# Unable to install or update anything on ParrotOS after breaking Python installation

Tags: package-management, python

I accidentally deleted all the Python dependencies but somehow managed to reinstall some of them. However now I am having issue in installing anything: it shows some kind of error with `apt-listchanges`. Everytime when is try to run upgrade/update command it shows same error which is

```
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/apt-listchanges: not found
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -lt 10 returned an error code (1)
E: Failure running script /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -lt 10
```

The file type of apt-listchanges file which is located in bin folder is `Python 3 script (text/x-python3)`. The operating system is Parrot-OS.

Also I've tried to install the `deb` package of `apt-listchanges` but failed

```
sudo dpkg -i apt-listchanges_3.22_all.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package apt-listchanges.
(Reading database ... 605517 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack apt-listchanges_3.22_all.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/apt-listchanges.prerm: 6: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: old apt-listchanges package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive apt-listchanges_3.22_all.deb (--install):
 new apt-listchanges package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Deferring configuration of apt-listchanges until /usr/bin/python3
and python's debconf module are available
/var/lib/dpkg/info/apt-listchanges.postinst: 212: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed apt-listchanges package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apt-listchanges_3.22_all.deb
```

I tried to install python minimals but it shows the same error of `apt-listchanges`. I don't know what to do.

Comment: i'm still facing this problem.